# How do I encode (base64) a PDF file's blob using javascript and decode in PHP to save in SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, blob, decoding

I have been trying for days now to build a file uploader using AJAX and PHP. I was able to upload images without any issue. But whenever it comes to PDF, I end up with blank pages.

Here is what I tried using FileReader:

```
for(const [key, file] of Object.entries($('input').prop('files'))){
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function(event){
    var object = {
      name:file.name,
      size:file.size,
      type:file.type,
      content:reader.result,
    }
    API.post("file/upload/?csrf="+CSRF,object,{
      success:function(result,status,xhr){
        console.log(result)
      }
    })
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

And in PHP:

```
// $_POST['content'] = base64_decode(str_replace('data:' . $_POST['type'] . ';base64,', '', $_POST['content']));
// $_POST['content'] = base64_decode($_POST['content']);
$_POST['content'] = base64_decode(urldecode($_POST['content']));
```

The results I got:

- Uploading an images: Ok!
- Uploading a single page PDF: PDF File only contains a blank page.
- The results are the same using the 3 methods (readAsDataURL,readAsBinaryString,readAsText).
- Using readAsText I keep getting: `Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

Validated once saved in SQL using phpMyAdmin 5.

Expected results should be that any file type should be saved correctly.

NOTE: The API class is just a small class that includes parameters for $.post so I don't have to type them all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem was that I was storing binary data in SQL which isn't meant for this type of use. This caused the SQL Database to corrupt the binary data.

Therefore, I redesign my file storage using locally stored Binary files (.bin) and SQL to provide all meta data of the files including the Path and more advanced ACL.

To secure the data, I use a rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^data/.*$ - [F,L]`. This prevents user from directly accessing the binary data. Therefore securing the file.

Once the changes made, I was able to save files through the application's API using the `readAsDataURL` method to retrieve the encoded binary data and send it over to the PHP API.

Comment: Adding a Rewrite Rule won't "secure" it. Your Regex wouldn't stop a Directory Traversal Attack from accessing your files. Instead, move the folder out of webroot and have your server-side language read them out of that location instead.

Comment: @maiorano84, ok good to know. Do you know of any other way though? I want to be able to publish the PHP Application for others to use on github. And I know for a fact that not all web hosting service offer this flexibility. I will make the suggestion on the software during installation though. So far, the RewriteRule seem to throw 403 errors when typing the URL directly.

Comment: The root of the project doesn't have to be the document root. Many projects already follow this practice. Take a look at Laravel and Symfony to see how you can structure your project without necessarily worrying about the user's server details.

Comment: @maiorano84 I build a php router and have setup an .htaccess file to only allow access to index.php and api.php. Is this what you are referring to?